# How to know "Status" Column in Leads Subpanel in Account Module in Sugarcrm CE?

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm, vtiger

Please how to know "Status" column through Coding in Leads Subpanel in Account Module. I am using SugarCRM Community Edition.

Answer (score 1):

It's so much easier to do in Studio:

Admin -> Studio -> Accounts -> Subpanels -> Leads.

Drag and drop the Lead's Status field into the Display table.

Do that after putting your your `/custom` directory in GIT or SVN, then you can analyze the code changes.